# Links nonresponsive when program is opened in Chrome

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs6

I am creating an interactive catalog for a retailer in flash/AS3. The links work fine when testing the .swf and published app, but not when the html file is opened. We want the customers to be able to just view the program in the browser so they don't have to install adobe air or flash player. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
kyP.kySBUY.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,kySBUY);    
function kySBUY(e:MouseEvent):void{
var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("https://www.filler.com");    
navigateToURL(request);    
}
```

Comment: I suggest you temporarily get the flash debug player installed and be sure there's no errors arising when it's executed in a browser, if you do get errors come back and update your question to get better responses: http://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/flash-player-google-chrome.html notice Chrome maintains it's own internal flash player, while this is basically good it means you have to do a little more work to get the debug player activated, check it here: http://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/find-version-flash-player.html if the problem persists but without errors try tracing things.

Comment: is it works fine in other browsers , especially in IE?